# How to call a function at the start of a PyQt python window?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I've tried to call my `keypress_request()` function when the app/form/window launches but it is not called?
Is there a way I can do that?

```
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from screenkeep import Ui_MainWindow
from keypress_m import perform_keypress
from multiprocessing import Process


class ScreenKeepProgram(Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ScreenKeepProgram, self).__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        # This below is the function I want to call
        # at the start of the program, with no success
        self.keypress_request()

    def keypress_action(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(5)
            perform_keypress('o')

    def keypress_request(self):
        do_keypress = Process(target=self.keypress_action)
        do_keypress.daemon = True
        do_keypress.start()
```

Comment: Do you have an `if __name__ == '__main__'` function?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with this code? What does `perform_keypress` do?